# Intellij IDEA: in a locked down environment, how do I register it to JetBrains?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, firewall

I'm working in a quite locked-down environment where any trafic is disallowed by default.  We can make specific request for ports/IP to be opened to allow commercial software we're using to "phone home" their license server.

Which IPs / ports do we need to open so that IntelliJ can contact JetBrains's license verification servers?

Which protocol should we allow (TCP or UDP or both?)?

And ideally: how much traffic should we expect the license check generate per launch / hour / day?

Comment: Have you tried contacting JetBrains about this?

Answer (score 2):

I try to give a answer from my experience. However, I'm no JetBrains salesman, so I don't know which licensing models exist besides the ones I know of.

I'm not aware, that IntelliJ will *phone home* when using permanent licenses. If you are using the commercial floating licenses model, you will need to set up a license server in your network which will assign licenses to your users on demand.

License keys are added to the license server instead of the IntelliJ installations directly, so I don't think that the license server or IntelliJ client will need to contact any JetBrains servers. The licensing server runs on port 8080 per default but since it's just an Apache Tomcat server, you could easily change that.

Regarding your questions about traffic: I captured three HTTP requests to the licensing server for starting and termination of the client. Total size of all requests/responses are about 4 kilobytes.

**References:**

- [Floating licenses](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/buy/buy.jsp#commercial_licenseServer)
- [License Server User Guide](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/LS/JetBrains+License+Server+User+Guide)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm running an individual permanent license.  I don't plan on installing the floating license server on my network.  Oh well I'll just try to install it without network access and entering the license and see if things work.  Thing is: the individual license allows you to run it on several computers, but only on one at a time (which makes sense).  I somehow wouldn't want to be "stuck" on my laptop because my desktop would be "blocking" my license key or something...  : )